# Simple line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to build a simple line chart but I stumbled into some problems.

The data I am loading is a `.tsv` file which looks like this:

```
date    frequency
Q1 '07  1000
Q2 '07  900
Q3 '07  700
Q4 '07  500
Q1 '08  450
Q2 '08  430
Q3 '08  400
```

And I am trying to draw the chart like this:

```
d3.tsv("./javascripts/data3.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  svg.selectAll(".line")
     .data(data)
     .enter().append("path")
     .attr("class", "line")
     .attr("d", d3.svg.area());
});
```

But instead of having a single line added like this:

```
<path class="line" d="M0,..." style="stroke: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></path>
```

I get multiple lines with no path:

```
<g transform="translate(40,20)">
<path class="line"></path>
<path class="line"></path>
<path class="line"></path>
<path class="line"></path>
<path class="line"></path>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `datum(mydata)` instead of `data(mydata)` will bind the data to a single SVG object rather than one per value.

Using [the example suggested above](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245#index.html) here's a fiddle that uses your data: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/2DQQc/3/

I've also modified to use the `d3.svg.area` path generator rather than `d3.svg.line` (assuming you've chosen that for a reason):

Your data also uses quarter numbers (Q1, Q2 ...) which are going to be a bit tricky to parse as dates. I've just replaced the Q numbers with month names, but if you need to do it properly see https://gist.github.com/biovisualize/5430237/